# rootfs readonly vs overlayfs

Tags: root, readonly

We need to have a read-only rootfs because of safety issues (no change to the FS in flash is possible).
Other writable partition can be used with the read-only rootfs (for logs for example).

In terms of simplicity we rather use the rootfs read-only way, instead of `overlayfs`. Yet, I am afraid that some process might try to write into rootfs and will then fail.

Our system is very tiny and minimal, it has only one or two process. (but also contains `selinux` and `auditd`).

Is it always possible in Linux system to use rootfs as read-only or is it required to use overlayfs in such cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible to have a read-only root filesystem. It's inconvenient and uncommon on server-type or workstation-type installations, but it's common on embedded systems. A read-only root filesystem has some limitations, mainly:

- You can't upgrade anything on it or add any software (except on other filesystems, e.g. with a `/usr/local` on a separate partition). This isn't a concern if you upgrade by replacing the filessytem image in flash as a whole.
- You can't reconfigure anything in `/etc`. This means that any configuration has to be done in a different way; typical solutions include:

  - through files in other directories (and then you need to configure the application differently);
  - via a symbolic link to another directory;
  - dynamically, e.g. by a script that reads configuration variables from NVRAM.

  Typical affected data includes the network configuration, the timezone, user authentication information, etc.
- If deploy the same filesystem image to multiple machines, you need to arrange for all the machine-specific data to be outside the filesystem image. This includes the host name, the SSH server key, etc.
- You do typically need some persistent writable files under `/var`, such as logs under `/var/log` and the random seed file (needed unless you have a hardware RNG).